# Build issues with Placenote iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, xcode10

I have been working on an app which already had integrated Placenote SDK through pods and it was working fine. Sometimes, it gave me build errors but after build clean up it was working fine.

Now, due to certain reasons, I need to update libraries and Placenote also get updated, and now I am facing persistent build failure with following error:

[image]
[image]

`symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Infinite build cleanups but nothing is solving my issue.

Please let me know if someone get me a fix.

````html
### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.7.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
    RubyGems : 2.5.2.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.14.4 (18E226)
       Xcode : 10.1 (10B61)
         Git : git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 664639fa034e3b1798282006c9c457c8086ffe64
               twilio - https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs @ 15612163b2cae5be50339701ce3702af12a090f8
```

### Installation Source

```
Executable Path: /usr/local/bin/pod
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
# AppDelegate.swift
# Bryan Cooper
# RocketCM
# The dependency installation file.
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'RocketCM' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for RocketCM
  
  # Apollo is the GraphQL code generation library.
  pod 'Apollo'
  # WebSocket provides network layer socket implementation for subscriptions.
  pod 'Apollo/WebSocket'
  # Crashlytics is a crash monitoring service.
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  # IQKeyboardManager manages the keyboard sessions to avoid recognizer errors.
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  # Fabric is a monitoring solution required for Crashlytics.
  pod 'Fabric'
  # FSCalendar is a calendar UI library.
  pod 'FSCalendar'
  # Firebase is the storage solution implementation.
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  # Database is the adapter for Firebase Realtime DB NoSQL.
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  # Storage is the adapter for Firebase Asset Store.
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  # Placenote is a SLAM implementation to stabilize AR content.
  pod 'PlacenoteSDK'
  # Google Maps is used to display a map with Google data sourcing.
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  # Google Places is used to geocode and reverse geocode location information.
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  # ColorPicker is a hue selection UI library.
  pod 'SwiftHSVColorPicker'
  # WheelPicker is a vertical and horizontal picker library.
  pod 'WheelPicker', '~> 1.0'

  target 'RocketCMTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'RocketCMUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```
````

Comment: There is a chance the SDK binary might be missing. Can you check the size of the file at Pods/PlacenoteSDK/Placenote.framework? What is the size of that particular file?

Comment: @pj_mukh I have worked on your steps from https://github.com/Placenote/PlacenoteSDK-iOS/issues/32. Placenote.framework has 8.3 MB file size. Also attaching screenshot.

Comment: @pj_mukh Pls find full SDK folder in this screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=17osflNtUuzoQpEOLkPkPB4RmCWaJt_fN

Comment: @pj_mukh I added my pod env into my question. Pls chk if its helpful.

Comment: @pj_mukh would you be able to answer this post? Its very hard to work with this SDK.

Comment: @PareshThakor Whats is swift Compiler language in your Build Settings?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani Swift compiler language is 4.2. You are referring to here?  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xH5KfNvsmEpKXdmu6N7dcSxGdiQwOSlp

Comment: @PareshThakor Not able to access without permission

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I shared access with you.

Comment: @PareshThakor There is only screenshot image try with remove pod from project and update pod.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I just added screenshot to make sure I am checking at correct place, what you are referring at. However, I tried lots of time removing and adding pods, also, executed git lfs commands and replaced .framework files from sample source code tar. Which resulted into a crash with error: - "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Placenote.framework/Placenote Reason: image not found"

Comment: @PareshThakor is it possible to share your project .zip so I can check it. or you can also try with update sudo gem cocoa pod into your project from your end.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I try quickly on this but I believe my pods are updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195049/discussion-between-nikunj-kumbhani-and-paresh-thakor).

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani Thanks for helping me out of the situation. My issue resolved when I placed 'install_framework "${PODS_ROOT}/PlacenoteSDK/Placenote.framework"' into my 'Pods-RocketCM-frameworks.sh'. It was crashing my app showing the "Image not found" error which was Placenote.framework/Placenote sdk.